# How to access site files on Azure

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

so my uncle asked me to update something on his website. I found out he uses azure service. I've never used this service before. After looking around I thought it was as easy as Searching App Services, then clicking on the only app running, then on the side panel click development center, then I choose FTP access. I then used FileZilla, I edited a file and then re-uploaded the file but nothing gets updated on the site. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there's really not a lot to go on, here. Using Azure's App Services (Web Apps) to run a site is fine, but we don't know anything about the site in question, nor where any files are stored.

Comment: Depending on the type of app, you may be able to update some of the assets via FTP.  What language/platform are you using?  Asp.Net with C#?  Node? More detail will help.  What are you trying to update?  Static text, css, js, what?

Comment: If your problem appears in the deploy your apps, you need to read document. If not, you can manage your site by kudu.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update your website, you can use FTP,Git or other tools. You can refer to this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp) which can tell you how to deploy your sites. And contains other way to deploy your app. According your describe, you can check the last modified time of files in kudu.The following paragraph will introduce kudu.

If you just want to update your static files in sites. The easiest way is logging on portal and find your app.

First, you should click Advanced Tool in left side, and click the link to open KUDU Management.

[image]

Second, find Debug console options and click CMD or PowerShell, then you can see folders in the page, click site->wwwroot .

[image]
[image]

Third, you can add/delete/modify your static files by buttons in the page. When click the icon of pen, you can modify this file.

[image]

If you want to copy your local files, you also can drop it to this page, it's very convenient. More function about Kudu  you can see this [site](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki).

Hope my answer works for you.