# Azure App Service not reflecting file changes from ftp

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure and I have created a very simple App Service in Azure with everything default. Changed the App Service Plan to B1. I can browse the app service home page and see the default page. I then connect using FTP and try to change the default page, but it did not reflect changes.

I even downloaded publish profile and published a .net core 3.1 web api with defaults, I can see the files are deployed using FTP but the api is not present. I even deleted the default page but the home page still appears. It seems the ftp is not pointing to default location where files are being picked up by asp.net core.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61087646/how-to-access-site-files-on-azure/61092149#61092149). Then use kudu to check whether the time of the last update file via FTP is consistent with the release time. If the file is not updated, of course this update has no effect. Then we can check the FTP connection str.

But first, I suggest you to modify `index.html` or default `interface function` and update by kudu. Then check if the update file is effective. If success, I can sure you code is ok.

Second, check your FTP Connection str.

Step 1. Find Deployment Center->FTP, click FTP then you can see Dashboard, into Dashboard find `FTPS Endpoint`,`Username` and `Password`.

[image]

Step 2. Use FileZilla, connect it. You can see files in it.

[image]

Then you can try again. Under normal circumstances, there is no problem to update via FTP.If the problem is still not resolved, I suggest that you can deploy to local IIS for debugging.

Comment: I figured out the problem is with .net core deployments on linux. They are not deployed when we upload using ftp. Either we need to publish from VS using **Linux App Service** or we need to create an Azure DevOps pipeline. The way around which I found was to use .NET 4.7 deployments, which are installed on windows and when deployed fom ftp changes reflect straight away.

Comment: I thought your description could not be deployed using FTP.  You can select the version of win or linux on Portal or VS at the time of creating apps. It cannot be changed after selection. But it should not affect your FTP update, right ?@Liono

Comment: I was able to deploy using FTP but the changes were not reflecting ,and yes that is right, once we create the app version as linux or windows we cannot change that, but funny thing is for windows (I tried an html app service and .NE 4.7) and we deploy using FTP, the changes appear as soon as they are uploaded using ftp. But if we have linux app service (I was struggling with both Node and .net core 3.1) uploading directly to FTP does not make the changes appear.

Comment: You are right, I also find it.  I read a post about it, you can read it. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872335/net-core-3-x-compatibility-with-net-framework-4-7#comment107734189_60872335`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem like, publish contain not displaying when visit website. then i change following settings and it worked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue updating files in FTP and the dlls weren't being updated as they were being used by the site. I had to stop the App Service first and then update the files. The changes then reflected when restarting it.